# Sequence contains no elements on http post

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

In an Httpost in asp.net core i get 
"sequence contains no elements"
The post should save on database Order and OrderItems

The strange is that in debug with break point i see the sequence has elements

```
var order = new Ordcli
        {
            Id= guid,
            year = model.Year,
            OrderDate = model.Date,
            ...
            OrderItems = model.OrderItems.Select(i => new Rows
            {
                Id = _ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).Max() + 1,
                ProductCode = i.Code,
                Qty = i.Qty
                ...
            }).ToList()
        };
```

Again if i put the mouse over the OrderItems i see the collection

Comment: `_ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).Max()`  line is causing the error. There is no rows.

Comment: what i shoud do to insert an Id ? in my composite key i cant add autoincrement

Comment: you can check if there are some rows before calling Max() : try something like _ctx.Rows.Any() ? _ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).Max() + 1 : 1

Comment: `ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().Max() + 1,`-Please try with this and let me know

Comment: yes seems correct! tks a lot ! bye

Comment: @gigiLaTrottola Give a upvote too please! I deserve it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).Max()` line is causing the error. So replace this line with the following:

```
ctx.Rows.Select(x => x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().Max() + 1
```